# Convert SVG to PDF using command line in Mac OSX

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, pdf, graphics

I want to convert a SVG file to PDF from the command line on Mac OSX. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's not exactly the command line, but https://gapplin.wolfrosch.com is a free app that provides AppleScript and Automator actions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using the `rsvg-convert` command.
You can install it using homebrew, just type:

```
brew install librsvg
```

After that you can convert SVG files to PDF using the following command:

```
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o file.pdf file.svg
```

Comment: This does not support embedded fonts unfortunately.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to handle an SVG an `<image>` with a base64-encoded SVG in it — produces a rasterized version of the embedded SVG

Answer (score 6):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) can be called on the command line, and you can convert SVG to PDF with:

```
inkscape --export-filename=out.pdf in.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the .svg with Safari and "File > Export as PDF..."

Comment: Good to know, the question asked for a command-line solution though.